# OLED on Hardware SPI, on DUE

Tags: arduino-due, spi, display

I want to use an OLED with DUE.
I plan to connect it via hardware SPI.
The Due has a 3X2 pin connector labeled SPI. Is it here where i connect the SCK and MOSI?

If indeed, i connect it here, then which one is SCK and which one is MOSI?

Most importantly, i saw somewhere that in the DUE, hardware digital pin 13 is SCK and pin 11 is MOSI?
Is this true? Because if it is, i can simply hook it up to these pins and get rid of the confusing 3X2 pin connector.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like it's true. There is only one `SPI` module and it has fixed pins which are not duplicated anywhere.

However there are three instances of `USART` which can be used in synchronous mode as `SPI`:

- **`USART0`**: `RXD0`(`PA10`) / `TXD0`(`PA11`) / `SCK0`(`PA17`)
- **`USART1`**: `RXD1`(`PA12`) / `TXD1`(`PA13`) / `SCK1`(`PA16`)
- **`USART2`**: `RXD2`(`PB21`) / `TXD2`(`PB20`) / `SCK2`(`PB24`)

Whole table from SAM3X datasheet:

[image]

But I'm not sure if the `Arduino IDE` supports this mode, or you'll have to do it from scratch by yourself.

You can even use `RTS` as select slave signal:
[image]